# snowflake Issue facing

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT DISTINCT PMSTPRT.I_SUPLR, P_PSLOC.I_SUPLR AS PSLOC_I_SUPLR, I_PART, PMSTPRT.N_SUPLR_STMPNG,
FROM PROCUREMENT.PMSTPRT  , AFTERSALES.P_PSLOC
WHERE PMSTPRT.I_MOD_YR = '' 
      AND (SUBSTR(PROCUREMENT.PMSTPRT.I_SUPLR,1,5)=AFTERSALES.P_PSLOC.I_SUPLR) 
ORDER BY PROCUREMENT.PMSTPRT.N_SUPLR_STMPNG, PROCUREMENT.PMSTPRT.I_SUPLR, PROCUREMENT.PMSTPRT.I_PART
```

join above query with below query on psloc_i_suplr and formatted_ship_to

```
SELECT MATNR, MAX(SHIP_DATE) FROM
  (SELECT MATNR, SHIP_DATE, SPLIT_PART(SHIP_TO, ' ', 1) AS FORMATTED_SHIP_TO FROM "zrmm") as t1
JOIN
  (SELECT I_SUPLR FROM "P_PSL") as t2
ON t1.FORMATTED_SHIP_TO = t2.I_SUPLR
GROUP BY MATNR
```

For one matnr there will be different formatted_ship_to , it should be like for a particular matnr, if formatted_ship_to and psloc_i_suplr matches then give max ship date for that

Output for present code:
[The present output is like in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzbVw.png)
[I should get only this row output because both formatted_ship_to and psloc_i_suplr are matching for that matnr number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv5rd.png)

We need to check for a particular matnr number if psloc_i_suplr and formatted_ship_to are matching or not